# Sort Values in SQL Table Using C# MVC Code

Tags: c#, html, sql, model-view-controller

I have this C# MVC code that refers to a SQL table. I have a SQL table called Machines with all the Machine names. How do I sort the Names in alphabetical order in the SQL table using this code?

The Controller Code:

```
 public class HomeController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        using (var db = new DatabaseModel())
        {
            var machines = db.Machines.ToList().Select(m => m.ToSelectListItem());

            ViewBag.MachineOptions = machines;
        }

        return View();
    }
}
```

I want the Names under Name column in the Machine table to be sorted alphabetically.

Machine Table:

```
  Id     Name
   1      HP500
   2      ABC234
   3      JH430
```

Comment: Why is this tagged HTML?  What do you mean by this code `"refers to a SQL table"` is it entity framework?  How do you imagine it would be possible to sort from the single instance anyway?  This class would refer to a single row of a table, you would have no context of the rest of the rows.

Comment: Please see my updated code above.

Comment: What do you want it sorted by?  You are expected to include a [MCVE] with your question

Comment: Do you want rows to be persisted sorted in database?

Comment: Does this work? `ViewBag.MachineOptions = machines.OrderBy(m => m.Text);`

Comment: Sorry about that guys. See my updated code above. I want the Machine Names in the Name column in the SQL table to be sorted in alphabetical order.

Comment: @techindustry do you want to literally resort the items **in your SQL table** or do you want them displayed sorted in your view?

Comment: It worked! Thanks, Rufus L!

Comment: @techindustry What you asked for is not what you wanted

Comment: and did you search for answer before asking?  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/getting-started/getting-started-with-ef-using-mvc/sorting-filtering-and-paging-with-the-entity-framework-in-an-asp-net-mvc-application

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're looking for **OrderBy**...

```
var machines = db.Machines
.OrderBy(m => m.Name)
.Select(m => m.ToSelectListItem());
.ToList()
```

Comment: Why `.ToList()` before the `Select()`?  That does not make a whole lot of sense to me

Comment: "in the Machine table to be sorted alphabetically" He wants Machine to be sorted inside table

Comment: Yes, better to do all the logic operations before called .ToList()

Comment: Yeah my code is a bit scattered, but the solutions above have worked. Thanks!

Comment: @techindustry Better to do the sort before, calling to list, as this will execute on the SQL Server, and not in code - which is more efficient.

Comment: why "ToList()" ? Why not ToArray() ?

Comment: @mrdnk how do you sort before putting it into list?

Comment: @RufusL Will the GetEnumerator be executed normally after db was disposed?

Comment: @techindustry as per my example. So .OrderBy(...).ToList() will execute the sort in SQL.  Essentially .ToList(), will execute the actually query, and anything before it such as OrderBy(...), is in simple terms setting up the SQL criteria to run.  Noting that all of these types of operations are generic interface methods, and can be run on any type of LINQ collections.

Comment: @techindustry whereas, .ToList().OrderBy(...), will fetch the data from the database, and then Order it.

Comment: Yeah I agree with you all, the values should be sorted before putting them into List. I tried what Rufus L and mrdnk asked me to try and both of your solutions worked! Thank you so much!

Comment: @techindustry glad I could help. You may want to look at creating an Interface with properties of Id and Name to make more Dropdown more generic (something I've done in the past, for dropdown list data, but that depends on where you are with your .NET

Answer (score 0):

> How do I sort the Names in alphabetical order in the SQL table using
>   this code?

If you want rows to be stored in another sorting way than by primary key - make another column a clustered index:

```
public class Machine
{
public int Id { get; set; }

[Index("NameClusteredIndex", IsClustered = true)]
public string Name { get; set; }

public SelectListItem ToSelectListItem()
{
    return new SelectListItem
    {
        Value = Id.ToString(),
        Text = Name
    };
}
```

}

Comment: I was a little vague about my question. But thanks for your help!

Comment: This solution is a little odd, since changing the clustered index is an overkill for what seems to be a simple query.

Comment: @DmitriM Simple query does not do the thing that is stated in quote

Comment: OP’s question is poorly constructed which makes things confusing. Yes, your answer is technically correct but what really is needed is an .OrderBy()

Answer (score -2):

As easy as that:

```
db.Machines.ToList().OrderBy(o => o.Name).Select(m => m.ToSelectListItem());
```

Comment: Why commit the items to memory before querying?

Comment: + "in the Machine table to be sorted", not the result to be sorted

Comment: Might be taking that too "literally"

Comment: well, I just added the .OrderBy() in the original code, which would solve the case...